# Google Action "cart preview card" is not displayed for Transactions in simulator

Tags: actions-on-google

**UPDATE:** I tried it from the Assistant app on my mobile and got the "cart preview card". But it is still not working in the simulator.

---

I was following the tutorial of using the Transaction API with Google Actions. [In this part](https://developers.google.com/assistant/conversational/df-asdk/transactions/physical/dev-guide-physical-reservations#3_propose_the_order) of the "Building Reservation" tutorial, it says the following

> The data presented in the "cart preview card" is rendered as-is according to your Order

I set the `ordersv3` argument to `true` on the `actionssdk` object as mentioned in the tutorial.

```
const app = actionssdk({
    clientId: clientId,    // needed for sign in
    ordersv3: true,
})
```

But when I tested it in the simulator, the "**cart preview card**" was not displayed. I was able to accept the proposed order and complete a transaction inside `actions.intent.TRANSACTION_DECISION` intent, but I did not see or hear any "cart preview card" information in the simulator.

I also tried following the [physical transactions tutorial](https://developers.google.com/assistant/conversational/df-asdk/transactions/physical/dev-guide-physical-custom) but ended up with the same result.

What I understood from the tutorials is that Google will take care of rendering the preview card according to the `order` object. Is this correct? Or do need to build the preview card myself?

Comment: When you use the simulator, what device type is being simulated? Can you share a screenshot?

Comment: @NickFelker, I tried with phone, smart screen, and speaker. Happened with all device types. Here's a [screenshot on smart screen](https://prnt.sc/ui40io). "Checkout" triggers the transaction and shows a cart preview card when I test on a real device.

Comment: This seems to be a bug in the simulator. I've reproduced it and escalated to the simulator team.